# jQuery for date convert in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, date-format

When I get date from database to interface it displays `/Date(1394908200000)/`. How do I fix that using below code?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/home/DisplaySeason',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {

        $("#tabledata tbody").empty();

        var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
        if (myData.Code === 1) {

            var tr = [];
            var sList = myData.Data;
            for (var i = 0; i < sList.length; i++) {

                tr.push('<tr>')
                tr.push("<td> " + sList[i].CarPlateNumber + " </td>");
                tr.push("<td> " + sList[i].Date + "</td>");
                tr.push("<td> " + sList[i].CardNo + "</td>");
                tr.push("<td><a id=\"TakeMyVechicle\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" onclick=\"updateFunction('" + sList[i]["id"] + "')\"> <i class=\"material- icons\"><b>Take My Vechicle</b></i>  </a></td>");

                tr.push('</tr>');
            }
        } 

        $("#tabledata tbody").empty();
        $('#tabledata').append($(tr.join('')));

    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a JS date object by using `eval` and a simple `regex`:

```js
var dateStr = "/Date(1394908200000)/";
var date = eval("new " + dateStr.replace(/\//g, ""));
console.log(date.toString())
```

You can create a function and use it:

```
function getDateStr(dateStr){
   var date = eval("new " + dateStr.replace(/\//g, ""));
   var month = date.getMonth() + 1; 
   return month + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
}

// Use like:
tr.push("<td> " + getDateStr(sList[i].Date) + "</td>");
```

Comment: /Date(1394908200000)/ this is depends on dates.if date coloumn has multiple dates values it will deferent valus.and how i bind out put to  tr.push("<td> " + sList[i].Date + "</td>"); coloumn

Comment: @ChathuskaChathuska Edited the answer

Comment: function (jsonDate) {
                           var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                           var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                           return month + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();           how i use this function to my above code???please help me

Comment: @ChathuskaChathuska Ive edited the code, but for more clarifications you need to open a different question. Mark this answer as accepted using the grey tick mark if it helped you

Comment: @ChathuskaChathuska Have you understood the solution or not?

Comment: i understood the solution.thak you very much for the help